# cURL works from Command Line but does not work from Browser

Tags: php, curl, windows-server-2008-r2

I have AMPPS installed on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have a code that uses cURL.

Running code from CLI, cURL works fine.

Running same code from browser, I get `cURL is not a function`, means cURL does not work.

I just purchased **Windows Server 2008 R2** server recently and has only 1 PHP installation.

Also I have checked `phpinfo()` from browser and `php -v` from CLI and both have same version of PHP.

Any idea whats going on?

Comment: It's right cURL isn't a PHP function. Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

most likely, my best guess:
your php-cli use a different php.ini than your apache2-mod-php, and `extension=php_curl.dll` is enabled in the php.ini used by php-cli, but is NOT enabled in the php.ini used by your apache mod php.  to verify, make a file with `<?php phpinfo();` and run it both in php-cli and apache, and check the `Loaded Configuration File`. and to fix, add the  extension=php_curl.dll (or whatever it's called in AMPPS) to the php.ini used by apache's php.

Comment: there is a php.ini file in `D:\Ampps\apache` but it has `extension=php_curl.dll` enabled

Comment: and when you run phpinfo(); what does php-cli say about `Loaded Configuration File` ? and what does apache say about `Loaded Configuration File` ?

Comment: ahh, seeing from browser it says 'D:\Ampps\apache\php.ini' ... and thats same file that has curl enabled in it

Comment: huh weird, then it's probably a startup error. set `display_startup_errors=On`, restart apache, and try again, you probably get a "curl module failed to load" error or simmilar